# Clicking Next doesn't render new comments. Manual refresh works though. Why?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

The route has:

```
queryParams: {
  page: {
    refreshModel: true
  }
},

model: function(params) {
  return this.store.findRecord('article', params.article_id);
},

setupController(controller, model) {
  let params = this.paramsFor(this.routeName);

  this.store.query('comment', { filter: { 'article-id': model.id }, page: { number: (params.page ? params.page : 1) } }).then(comments => {
    controller.set('comments', comments);
  })
}
```

Controller has:

```
queryParams: ['page'],
page: null,
```

And template:

```
{{#link-to “articles.show” model.id (query-params page=pageMeta.next) class="button -blue -mini"}}Next{{/link-to}}
```

Clicking on `Next` takes me to `http://localhost:4099/articles/7?page=2`, but the `comments` in the template are not refreshed. But when I manually refresh the page. The new comments are shown.

It seems like the `query params` in `setupController` isn't being updated. What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Does moving the comment query out of setupController and into an `afterModel` hook work?

Comment: Yeap an `afterModel` hook seems to work. But is this the right approach/pattern for this scenario?